# How to intercept command stdin and stdout from bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stdin

Have a binary application in linux (centos 7) and need capture all text received and expulsed, by example:

```
[ssh stdin&stdout] -> [my-command] -> [/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server piped]
```

the idea is to be able to observe in the terminal all the input and output messages of the target application. Is it possible using only bash ?, I know that it is possible to create an application that takes the input and passes it to a piped execution and displays the content in the terminal but I want to know if it is possible natively.

Answer (score 0):

If you run two instances of your program, for instance tee, then you could:

```
tee stdin.txt | sftp-server |& tee stdout-stderr.txt
```

or if you want to split stdout and stderr with 3 instances:

```
{ tee stdin.txt | sftp-server 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee stderr.txt ; } 3>&1 1>&2 | tee stdout.txt
```